# C# Error reading two dates from a binary file

Tags: c#, date

When reading two dates from a binary file I'm seeing the error below:

**"The output char buffer is too small to contain the decoded characters, encoding 'Unicode (UTF-8)' fallback 'System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback'. Parameter name: chars"**

My code is below:

```
static DateTime[] ReadDates()
{
    System.IO.FileStream appData = new System.IO.FileStream(
       appDataFile, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

    List<DateTime> result = new List<DateTime>();
    using (System.IO.BinaryReader br = new System.IO.BinaryReader(appData))
    {
        while (br.PeekChar() > 0)
        {
            result.Add(new DateTime(br.ReadInt64()));
        }
        br.Close();
    }
    return result.ToArray();
}

static void WriteDates(IEnumerable<DateTime> dates)
{
    System.IO.FileStream appData = new System.IO.FileStream(
       appDataFile, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);

    List<DateTime> result = new List<DateTime>();
    using (System.IO.BinaryWriter bw = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(appData))
    {
        foreach (DateTime date in dates)
            bw.Write(date.Ticks);
        bw.Close();
    }
}
```

What could be the cause? Thanks

Comment: since you are reading from a file, you could use while (appData.Position < appData.Length) instead of the PeekChar which is causing your problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `PeekChar` - that's trying to decode *binary* data as if it were a UTF-8 character. Unfortunately, I can't see anything else in `BinaryReader` which allows you to detect the end of the stream.

You *could* just keep calling `ReadInt64` until it throws an `EndOfStreamException`, but that's pretty horrible. Hmm. You could call `ReadBytes(8)` and then `BitConverter.ToInt64` - that would allow you to stop when `ReadBytes` returns a byte array with anything less than 8 bytes... it's not great though.

By the way, you don't need to call `Close` explicitly as you're already using a `using` statement. (That goes for both the reader and the writer.)

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for the help. Could I trouble you for a snippet of coding showing how I'd use ReadBytes(8) and BitConverter.ToInt64? Many thanks

Comment: @Jamie: I'm afraid I haven't got time right now, but basically loop round, calling ReadBytes(8) and checking whether the resulting byte array has 8 bytes in it or not. If not, you're done. If it has, call BitConverter.ToInt64 to get the long value to then construct the date from.

Answer (score 1):

I think Jon is correct that it's `PeekChar` that chokes on the binary data.

Instead of streaming the data, you could get it all as an array and get the values from that:

```
static DateTime[] ReadDates() {
  List<DateTime> result = new List<DateTime>();
  byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(appDataFile);
  for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i += 8) {
    result.Add(new DateTime(BitConverter.ToInt64(data, i)));
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to your problem would be to explicitly specify ASCII encoding for the `BinaryReader`, that way `PeekChar()` uses only a single byte and this kind of exception (a .NET bug, actually) doesn't happen:

```
using (System.IO.BinaryReader br = new System.IO.BinaryReader(appData, Encoding.ASCII))
```